# Changed my facebook account to a page, now I can't add likes from external sites to the page

Tags: facebook

What I used to do is like videos on my site and the URL + my comment would be added to my facebook account. Because the facebook account was used for my site only and my amount of friends increased quickly, I thought a page would be more suited. I changed this, al my friends turned into followers and I was happy... for a moment.

When I click the like button on my site now, the URLs + comments are not added to my page. I think this has to do with my fb:admins value. I used the one that worked with my account, but that doesn't work anymore. I changed it to my page id, but I read in another thread here that you can't use page id's as value for fb:admins.

My question is: How can I put the likes on my page, like I always did on my account?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. Can you give some actual examples?

Comment: So you did switch to act as business page, then went to some page and liking didn't result in link being posted to the page?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to say :)